# Java Require "this" in the constructor of the inheriting class

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have the following classes: Command, ParameterData, and TestCommand. Command is an abstract class that represents a simple object. This class requires a list of ParameterData objects. ParameterData, in turn, also requires an instance of the Command class in its constructor. I wanted to create a class inheriting from Command, i.e. TestCommand. Here's the problem: when invoking the constructor, I get a compile error: "Cannot reference 'this' before supertype constructor has been called". I don't know how to fix this problem. I will be grateful for your help.

Command class:

```
public abstract class Command {
    private final String SETTINGS_PATH;

    private final List<ParameterData> PARAMETERS;

    public Command(String settingsPath, List<ParameterData> parameters) {
        this.SETTINGS_PATH = settingsPath;
        this.PARAMETERS = parameters;
    }

    public String getSettingsPath() {
        return SETTINGS_PATH;
    }

    public abstract void run();
}
```

ParameterData class:

```
public class ParameterData {
    private final String SETTINGS_KEY;

    private final Command COMMAND;

    private final OptionType OPTION_TYPE;

    private final boolean REQUIRED;

    public ParameterData(String settingsKey, Command command, OptionType optionType, boolean required) {
        this.SETTINGS_KEY = settingsKey;
        this.COMMAND = command;
        this.OPTION_TYPE = optionType;
        this.REQUIRED = required;
    }

    public String getSettingsKey() {
        return SETTINGS_KEY;
    }

    public String getSettingsPath() {
        return COMMAND.getSettingsPath() + ".Parameters." + SETTINGS_KEY;
    }

    public OptionType getOptionType() {
        return OPTION_TYPE;
    }

    public boolean isRequired() {
        return REQUIRED;
    }
}
```

TestCommand class (error occurs with "this"):

```
public class TestCommand extends Command {
    public TestCommand() {
        super("Settings.TestCommand",
                List.of(new ParameterData("SettingsKey", this, OptionType.STRING, true)));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically the OP is not passing `this` to the super constructor, but to the constructor of `ParameterData`. I can't think of a way to solve this without making `PARAMETERS` in `Command` non-final and then setting it from the child constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how to fix this problem.

It cannot be fixed. You can't hand an instance of `this` around when your `this` reference isn't initialized yet. Think about it, it's a chicken and egg problem: That `this` reference has all sorts of crazy stuff going on. It'll have `final` fields that aren't initialized yet, i.e. final fields whose value will be changing if you query it.

Within the chain of constructors, thems the breaks. But you're not allowed to aggravate this problem by sending `this` to other places when `this` isn't "ready yet". Constructors are part of the 'birth' of an object and `this` refers to the baby. You can't hand your baby to others to coo at when it's not (fully) born yet.

If you want 2 objects that refer to each other, both with `final` fields? Not possible.

Make one field non-final. Use a builder system and make the 'setters' for this non-final field package private or fully `private` and whilst the field isn't final, your object will still be immutable for all intents and purposes - it cannot be observed to change once it escapes its package.